# Java dependencies. The following modules must have the same JDK assigned because of cyclic dependencies

Tags: maven, java, модули, зависимости

Речь идет о java проекте с использованием maven и POM dependencies (только начал с ними знакомиться)

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Есть модуль1, который содержит в себе еще два модуля (модуль2 и модуль3), в модуле2 есть интерфейс(СatInterface), а модуле3 класс, который реализует этот интерфейс(CatImpl). В классе Main, который находиться в модуле1, я создал объект класса CatImpl и вызвал метод doSomething().

При запуске программы Idea бросает error "The following modules must have the same JDK assigned because of cyclic dependencies between them:
"модуль2"
"модуль3"
Please update modules configuration"

Как можно решить проблему? Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваш POM. Возможно у вас в теге версий или конфигурации разные версии JDK. Также возможно, что вы понимаете под модулями?Может быть [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037657/stop-intellij-idea-to-switch-java-language-level-every-time-the-pom-is-reloaded) ответ поможет

Comment: @Dred добавил скрины POM

Comment: забыли parent POM?

Comment: @Dred сорри, добавил

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте исправить вашу структуру вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, сделайте в корневой папке общий POM, который будет в себя включать все ваши 3 помника